# Pipenv shell won't open an environment in current directory

Tags: django, terminal, pipenv

When I create a new directory and change to it, I try to start a new pipenv environment and it opens to my root directory. I was messing with my path, adding geckodriver, and that seemed to have thrown it off.

Here's my terminal:

christopherchough@Christophers-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd ~/Desktop
christopherchough@Christophers-MacBook-Pro Desktop % mkdir superlists && cd superlists
christopherchough@Christophers-MacBook-Pro superlists % pipenv install django
Installing django...
Resolving django...
Installing...
Adding django to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (c91b9a)...
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
christopherchough@Christophers-MacBook-Pro superlists % pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
. /Users/christopherchough/.local/share/virtualenvs/christopherchough-PpcwrOBl/bin/activate
christopherchough@Christophers-MacBook-Pro ~ %  . /Users/christopherchough/.local/share/virtualenvs/christopherchough-PpcwrOBl/bin/activate
(christopherchough) christopherchough@Christophers-MacBook-Pro ~ %

I was expecting it to show:

(superlists) christopherchough@Christophers-MacBook-Pro superlists ~ %